# convert ip short notation into CIDR notation

Tags: php, ip, cidr

suppose I have  a list like this below (in array $ips) which includes simple ip addresses and ip in short ip notation style.

```
125.45.
201.35.1.
35.89.18.27
101.135.2
222.122
78.56.21.146
```

how to convert them to ip Hyphenated range using php ?

i.e. the result should be

```
125.45.0.0-125.45.255.255
201.35.1.0-201.35.1.255
35.89.18.27
101.135.2.0-101.135.2.255
222.122.0.0-222.122.255.255 
78.56.21.146
```

Comment: There's not much to go on .. Are these IPs in an array?  Are then in a text file?  Individual strings passed into a function?

Comment: I have it in array $ips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, that I did this as a fun experiment.  Your question was a little vague, and you showed no attempt to actually to this yourself.  That being said, this function should accomplish what you are wanting.  Let me explain what it does:

First thing, checks if last character in the ip is a dot and removes it.

Second, count the number of ranges your IP has.

Third use a `switch/case` statement (cleaner than `if elseif` IMHO) to determine what to do with the string, based on IP range.

Lastly define the starting range and the ending range and concatenate them.

Finally return result.

```
<?php

$ips = array();


$ips[0] = '125.45.';
$ips[1] = '201.35.1.';
$ips[2] = '101.135.2';
$ips[3] = '222.122';
$ips[4] = '78.56.21.146';


foreach($ips as $ip){

echo "\n\nNEW IP RANGE: " . convert_ip($ip) . "\n\n";

}

function convert_ip($ip){

$ip = rtrim($ip, '.');

$ip_count = count( explode('.', $ip) );

switch ($ip_count) {

    case 1:

        $starting_ip = $ip . '.0.0.0';

        $ending_ip = $ip . '.255.255.255';

        $return_ip = "$starting_ip-$ending_ip";

        break;
    case 2:

        $starting_ip = $ip . '.0.0';

        $ending_ip = $ip . '.255.255';

        $return_ip = "$starting_ip-$ending_ip";

        break;
    case 3:

        $starting_ip = $ip . '.0';

        $ending_ip = $ip . '.255';

        $return_ip = "$starting_ip-$ending_ip";

        break;
    case 4:

        $return_ip = $ip;

        break;

    default:
        $return_ip = 'Unknown';
}

return $return_ip;

}

?>
```

> NEW IP RANGE: 125.45.0.0-125.45.255.255
>
> NEW IP RANGE: 201.35.1.0-201.35.1.255
>
> NEW IP RANGE: 101.135.2.0-101.135.2.255
>
> NEW IP RANGE: 222.122.0.0-222.122.255.255
>
> NEW IP RANGE: 78.56.21.146